# While True loop - invalid syntax

Tags: loops, while-loop, syntax

i get a invalid syntax to something really simple, can you help me. Where is my mistake.

[image: Code]

[image: Error]

I tried to fix it several times but without success.

Comment: the error message shows no colon after the `while true` also it is lower case `t` on true, does your code run? it looks syntactically correct to me, I'm not sure what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The code does not match the error. Are you running the wrong file?